# To see more than pointers in an array (objective C)

Tags: objective-c

If i enumerate an array i get

```
<myArray: 0x71b26b0> 
<myArray: 0x71b2830> 
<myArray: 0x71b2900>
```

I could take it that myData is behind the pointers listed, but if I wanted to explicitly see (log) the contents at each address, how to do that?

I have tried the &myData to no avail

--

for the benefit of uchuugaka:

```
-(void)loadObservedItems{
    NSString *path = [self observationFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        myArray = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"ObserveKey"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    } else {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    }
NSLog(@" %@",myArray);
}
```

Comment: well it helps to show the code. We can't see what you ARE doing

Comment: Implement the `description` method for your class.

Comment: ... to expand on @HotLicks' comment — implement `description` on your class and then just log the array directly. Its description knows how to call and compile the descriptions of its objects. No need to enumerate, to iterate or anything else.

Comment: Yep, `description` is equivalent to `toString` in Java, et al.  The person who writes the class gets to decide what it returns.  And when you NSLog something using the `%@` format descriptor, `description` is automatically called.

Comment: (A simple way to implement `description` is to create an NSDictionary containing a field name/field value entry for each field in your object, then return `[descriptionDict description]`.  This formats nicely with minimal effort, and it's easy to maintain as you add/delete fields.)

Comment: thanks to all - I'll try `description` and get back to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to MyClass.m:

```
-(NSString*)description {
    NSMutableDictionary* descDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [descDict addObject:someField forKey:@"someField"]
    [descDict addObject:anotherField forKey:@"anotherField"];
    [descDict addObject:yetAnotherField forKey:@"yetAnotherField"];
    return [descDict description];
}
```

Then just use `NSLog(@"myObject is %@", myObject);`.  Just like the big guys.

Slightly more sophisticated is to (within the method) pre-pend your class name and the object address to the result string, but that's usually unnecessary for simple debugging.

But I *think* you can do that like this:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", [super description], [descDict description]];
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. strange thing is in a test bed class to one side i did pretty well much the same and it shows the contents of the array, as opposed to pointers. I could just accept the contents are there and move on but i feel i ought to know why